# Applying CHMOD and zipping a file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, chmod

Is it better to gzip a file before or after applying chmod to it.

If I apply the chmod, then gzip it, and then unzip it, will it maintain the chmod?

Comment: you should test this yourself. Use small files. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man gzip`:

> gzip preserves the mode, ownership and timestamps of files when compressing or decompressing.

In other words, when compressing, the compressed file will have the same ownership and permissions as the original file.  When uncompressing, the uncompressed file will have the same ownership and permissions as the .gz file.

So,  no, it doesn't matter in which order you gzip or chmod.